# Plot with intermediate colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I've seen many questions regarding coloring plots, palettes, color maps, etc. I just want to have intermediate colors between the default w, m, g, k, b, r.

For instance I want my plot below to be gray instead of black.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

a = np.linspace(1., 4., 6)
b = np.array([3,4.,5.3,7.,8,0])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(a,b,'ko-',)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried `plt.plot(a, b, 'ko-', color='grey')` yet?

Comment: @Camon: No... but now I know how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can define colours in many ways with `matplotlib`. From the docs for [`plt.plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot):

> In addition [*to the abbreviations that you listed above*], you can specify colors in many weird and wonderful ways, including full names ('green'), hex strings ('#008000'), RGB or RGBA tuples ((0,1,0,1)) or grayscale intensities as a string ('0.8'). Of these, the string specifications can be used in place of a fmt group, but the tuple forms can be used only as kwargs.

So, some examples to get grey in your plot:

```
plt.plot(a,b,'o-',color='grey')

plt.plot(a,b,'o-',color='#808080')

plt.plot(a,b,'o-',color=(0.5,0.5,0.5)

plt.plot(a,b,'o-',color='0.5')
```